# PHP SESSION cant store variable from GET form variable

Tags: php, wordpress, session, get

```
<?
session_start();

 $_SESSION['name'] = "$_GET["name"]";
 $_SESSION['email'] = "$_GET["email"]";
 $session_id=session_id();
 
echo"$session_id <br>  $_SESSION['name'] <br> $_SESSION['email']";

?>
```

I am trying to create a session to store visitor input form with GET method, I cant use POST because the form is handled by wordpress plugins and the client only gave me the GET option. The problem is:

1. On page #1, this is the page after we submit the form, the echo is shown complete.
2. At page #2, I already add `session_start();` at top but `$_SESSION['name']` and $_SESSION['email'] keep empty (change page) but $session_id is stored and show same.

What am I missing? or maybe $_SESSION is cant store $_GET?

Comment: `$_SESSION['name'] = "$_GET["name"]";` is not even syntactically valid, this should give you nothing but a parse error. _“At page #1 this is page after we submit the form, the echo is show complete”_ - no, not with _that_ code as you have shown us, because that won’t even execute.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I cant use POST because the form is handled by wordpress plugins and client only gave me the GET option hahaha

Comment: @CBroe yeah it may wrong, sorry i not really good in php, in real .php script I did like this:
$email_=$_GET['email'];
 $_SESSION['email'] = "$email_";

Comment: Thanks @DamianDziaduch for support _/\_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So on the first page you save the values from the user input and it works as expected.

However, when you go to the second page, your code is overriding the session with new variables, which are empty in this case. Before assigning anything to the session, you should check whether it is not empty / valid.

For this simple code I would recommend checking via isset / array_key_exists functions.

Comment: THANKS! is work! 
$email_=$_GET['email']; 

if (isset($email_)) {   
 $_SESSION['email'] = "$email_";
}

I got it, so need check first then register, later if empty, it will check first. thanks Damian _/\_